# Gradient of a multivariate function numpy

Tags: python, gradient, numpy, calculus

I'm trying to calculate the gradient of multivariate function g using NumPy.

`g = lambda w: -np.sin(np.pi*np.sum(w**2)) + np.log(np.sum(w**2))`

`gradient = lambda w: ...`

the parameter w is a vector, for example, w = np.array([0.5,0.5]). I calculated the gradient like this;
`gradient = lambda w: np.pi*np.sum(2*w)*-np.cos(np.pi*np.sum(w**2)) + np.sum(2*w)*(1/np.sum(w**2))`

It does not give meaningful results. Is this formula correct or not?

Comment: Apply the Chain Rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we write it more explicitly,
$$f(w)=-\sin\left(\pi\sum w_i^2\right)+\ln \left(\sum w_i^2\right)$$

$${\partial f \over \partial w_i}=-\cos\left(\pi\sum w_i^2\right)\pi2w_i+\frac{2w_i}{\sum w_i^2}$$

So, the derivative is a vector; which means your expression will look like

```
gradient = lambda w: -np.pi*2*w*np.cos(np.pi*np.sum(w**2)) + 2*w*(1/np.sum(w**2))
```

when used denominator layout.

Comment: Thanks. w is an array which consists of w0 and w1, for example w = np.array([0.5,0.5]). In this case np.sum(w^2) is equivalent to w0^2 + w1^2, so I considered the derivation (2 * w0 + 2 * w1) which is equivalent to np.sum(w*2).

Comment: Why do you sum the derivatives?

Comment: Because in the function there is np.sum(w^2) part which is equivalent to w0^2 + w1^2. The parameter w is a 2-element array, the square roots of w0 and w1 added in the function, so I think the derivative of (w0^2 + w1^2) part should be np.sum(2*w).

Comment: No, derivative of w0^2 + w1^2 wrt w0 is 2w0, and wrt w1 is 2w1. You do not sum the derivatives.

Comment: That is correct, in none of them it’s summed.